# Tablela auxiliar com PK composta

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Tenho uma tabela fornecedor:

```
@Entity(name = "tbl_fornecedor")
public class Fornecedor extends PessoaJuridica implements Serializable, Desativar {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String cnpj;

    /*Relacionamentos*/
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fornecedor")
    private Set<FornecedorProduto> fornecedorProduto = new HashSet<FornecedorProduto>();


    /*Gettes and Setters*/      

}
```

Uma tabela Produto:

```
@Entity(name = "tbl_produto")
public class Produto implements Serializable, Desativar {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String codigoOriginal;

    @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "descricao", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name = "margem_lucro", nullable = false)
    private double margemLucro;

    @Column(name = "locacao", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String locacao;

    @Column(name = "Ativo")
    protected boolean ativo;

    /*Relacionamentos*/
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "produto")
    private Set<FornecedorProduto> fornecedorProduto = new HashSet<FornecedorProduto>();

    /*Getters and Setters*/
}
```

E a tabela Auxiliar:

```
@Entity(name = "tbl_fornecedor_produto")
   public class FornecedorProduto implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "preco_custo", nullable = false)
   private double precoCusto;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   @Column(name = "data_registro", nullable = false)
   private Date dataRegistro = new 
   java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

   @Column(name = "preco_atual", nullable = false)
   private boolean precoAtual;

   /*Relacionamentos*/
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "cnpj_fornecedor", updatable = false)
   private Fornecedor fornecedor;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "id_produto", updatable = false)
   private Produto produto;

   /*Getters and Setters*/  
}
```

Queria alterar a tabela auxiliar para que os Ids dos produtos e dos fornecedores fossem as PKs desta classe auxiliar, para remover este campo Id. Gostaria de uma luz a respeito deste quesito, qual melhor procedimento a tomar?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a notação `@Embeddable` e criar uma classe só para ser a PK, remova também os atributos id e transfira os atributos fornecedor e produto para a nova classe "PK", ficaria algo assim:
**Classe FornecedorProduto**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity(name = "tbl_fornecedor_produto")
public class FornecedorProduto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private FornecedorProdutoPK fornecedorProdutoPK;

    //get e set ...
}
```

**Classe FornecedorProdutoPK**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import br.com.foodadmin.model.Produto;

@Embeddable
public class FornecedorProdutoPK implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6921240056133407249L;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_produto", nullable=false)
    private Produto produto;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_fornecedor", nullable=false)
    private Fornecedor fornecedor;

    //get e set 
}
```